# Different bg images when selected/hover on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Maybe it's just an off-day for me, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this right now & I'm not finding much help elsewhere online.

Here's what I need to do:

In WordPress, I need a menu that instead of the usual..."just change a color when you're hovering over the menu item or when that's your current page"...each menu item has a separate bg image that swaps with yet another version of the appropriate bg image when hovered over or on the current page.

Here's the end product of what I wish to accomplish:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRGN7.jpg

Help?

Comment: Is that a non-web font?

Answer (score 0):

One method is when you're in the wordpress menu section and you goto the advance options on the top and enable css classes you can assign as class that has a hover sprite for that menu item. Then I believe Wordpress adds a active class for that menu item so it could always be like .yourmenuitem .current-menu-item which would select the current one. Then assign a background-position on it so it toggles the sprite. But you can get creative with it.

Example:

```
#menu-item-38 {
    background-image: url(your image);
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

#menu-item-38:hover {
    background-position: -40px 0;
}

#menu-item-38 .current-menu-item {
    background-position: -40px 0;
}
```

Comment: The theme I'm using that I'm trying to edit gives each menu item a number (ie - #menu-item-38) & then spits out a .selected class for the current page. I guess I'm having trouble targeting each individual ID to display "x" then hide "x" when "y" is hovered over or when "y" is the current page. Any suggestions on how to get started? (I'm a sleep-deprived guy who's just step or two above CSS noob status, so any help would be nice now...)

Comment: If you're not too familiar I would look into css sprites, that way it loads the entire image and you do not get a flicker on hovers when it loads the new image. A good source to learn more about CSS is CSS Tricks